Firebase download files from storage with react app
I have the following code
const fetchFiles = async () => {
    try {
      const eventDoc = await getDoc(doc(db, "events", id));
      if (eventDoc.exists()) {
        const eventData = eventDoc.data();
        const fileData = eventData.eventFiles || [];

        // Fetch URLs for each file
        const filesWithUrls = await Promise.all(
          fileData.map(async (file) => {
            const itemPath = `events/${id}/${file.name}`;
            const itemUrl = await fetchItemUrl(itemPath); // Use fetchItemUrl to get the URL
            const collectionType = "events";
            const collectionID = id;
            return { ...file, id: file.name, itemUrl, itemPath, collectionID, collectionType }; // Include imageUrl in the returned object
          })
        );

        setFileRows(filesWithUrls); // Update state with the new data
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Error fetching files: ", e);
    }
  };

  const fetchItemUrl = async (itemPath) => {
    const itemRef = ref(storage, itemPath);
    try {
      const metadata = await getDownloadURL(itemRef); // Use await to wait for the promise to resolve
      return metadata; // This will return the URL (or metadata) to the caller
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching item URL:", error); // Log or handle the error as needed
      return null; // Return null or an appropriate value to indicate failure
    }
  };

  const downloadFile = (url) => {
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = url;
    link.download = url.split("/").pop(); // Set the filename as the last part of the URL
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  };

{
      field: "edit",
      headerName: "edit",
      align: "right",
      flex: 0.8,
      renderCell: (params) => (
        <>
          <IconButton
            aria-label="download"
            onClick={() => {
              downloadFile(params.row.itemUrl);
            }}>
            <DownloadIcon />
          </IconButton>
          {user &&
            (user.privileges >= 2 ||
              (Array.isArray(user.adminAccess) && user.adminAccess.includes("deleteFile"))) && (
              <IconButton aria-label="delete" onClick={() => setDeleteFile(params.row)}>
                <DeleteForeverIcon />
              </IconButton>
            )}
        </>
      ),

Somewhy the download works only for Powerpoint / word while images and PDF display in the window instead of downloading.
I tried using getBlob by firebase but for some reason I'm getting
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at url/o/events%2FOcCYB9tIHaVfoH8c5w9z%2F%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%99%20%D7%AA%D7%A7%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%AA.pdf?alt=media. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.
in the console
Any help or tips are appreciated as I couldn't get a solution elsewhere
